# iOS captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler: dark image

Tags: ios

I am using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` to capture photos in my app. Unfortunately when a user takes a shot right after the view opens the image is very dark, for iPhone 4s & iPhone 5 almost black.

As suggested in other SO questions/answers, I implemented KVO for adjustments to exposure, focus and whitebalance and wait for these to stop. But still after implementing this, images are still dark when captured right after setting up the session.

Any ideas?

I use `sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`